# incorrect output when prints too many '\n' in C

Tags: c

Output the first n items of Fibonacci series, and use `'\n'` to wrap lines after each output. It is extremely strange that when the number of items is above `29`, the output will have problems.

Here is my source code.  The initial idea is to output 40 items.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 40

int main(void)
{
    int fib_number[N] = { 0, 1 };
    
    printf("%d\n%d\n", 0, 1);
    for (int i = 2; i < N; i++)
    {
        fib_number[i] = fib_number[i - 2] + fib_number[i - 1];
        printf("%d\n", fib_number[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

When `N` is `29`, there is no problem with the output:

```
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
144
233
377
610
987
1597
2584
4181
6765
10946
17711
28657
46368
75025
121393
196418
317811
```

Next is the case when `N` is `30` or beyond `30`, and there is a slight problem with the output.

(`N` = 30)

```
1                                                                                                                       1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
144
233
377
610
987
1597
2584
4181
6765
10946
17711
28657
46368
75025
121393
196418
317811
514229
```

In addition to the absence of any numbers in the first line and the seemingly missing line break in the last line, there is another subtle issue: there are a large number of spaces after the `1` in the second line.

When `N` is `40`, the problem is even more serious:

```
89
144
233
377
610
987
1597
2584
4181                                                                                                                    89
144
233
377
610
987
1597
2584
4181
6765
10946
17711
28657
46368
75025
121393
196418
317811
514229
832040
1346269
```

If I replace `'\n'` with `' '`, there will be no problem with the output:

```
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181 6765 10946 17711 28657 46368 75025 121393 196418 317811 514229 832040 1346269 2178309 3524578 5702887 9227465 14930352 24157817 39088169 63245986
```

This makes me feel very bad, as I can only try to change the implementation for a problem that I have no idea about the reason.
Can someone tell me what the problem is, otherwise I may not be able to use `'\n'` without any concerns in the future.

Comment: OT: You don't need an array of all the numbers. All you need are the two previous numbers.

Comment: [ideone](https://ideone.com/SamgA0) behaves as expected. It may be an issue with your terminal / environment / system ??? **You should be able to use `'\n'` with no problems, it's a building block of the whole C thing `:-)`**

Comment: OP code, with `40`, works fine for me (using **ancient** compiler...) Helpdesk obligatory: "_Have you tried turning it off and on again?_"

Comment: In what terminal (emulator) do you run your program? Are you using Windows, macOS or Linux?

Comment: try to add `setbuf(stdout, NULL); `  to start of your program to disable buffering

Comment: OT: when `n` reaches 48 there will be another problem because 2971215073 is out the range of `int`.

Comment: Looks like a terminal problem. In the last example the sequence is repeating. What happens when you redirect the output to a file?

Comment: The program works fine (except that at some point the Fibonacci numbers cannot fit in 32bits and the values will wrap around). The terminal is incorrectly set.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I understand what you mean, but my original intention was to try to find the cause of this problem. Now it seems that changing the IDE may be a wise choice.

Comment: @axiac Concerning overflow: Code should handle `N ==47` with `fib[46]` --> 1,836,311,903.  Also "wrap around" is common, yet `int` overflow is simply UB.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, I am aware of this potential issue and know how to avoid it. Thank you for the reminder. As a beginner, I actually don't understand how to output to a file. Now I plan to switch to an IDE.

Comment: @qopm Does adding a `fflush(stdout)` right after `printf("%d\n", fib_number[i]);` help ?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Unfortunately, it has no effect on the result.

Comment: @j.holetzeck Thank you for your reply, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @qopm I was wondering if the broken output was sensitive to 128 characters and/or was looking for a `"\r\n"`.  I doubt the issue relates to the fib calculation.  Good luck.

Comment: @pmg Thank you for your reply.  I will try to use a new IDE :  )

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Okay, thank you :  )

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom it's windows.

Comment: If you run the program from a console (CMD.EXE), you can redirect the output with, for example, `myprog > result.txt`. The IDE may have a way to do that too.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I can't understand what just happened: I installed Visual Studio and ran the program in it. If I remember correctly, the first run included fflush(stdout);,but that's not the point.Except for the first run, which had a normal result, the results of other runs were all problematic!I restarted the software, but to no avail.

Comment: @qopm The simplest explanation is that your IDE has an input/output bug.  File a report. Get a $$$ refund.  Or if it cost $0.00, you get what you paid for.  Again, good luck.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you for your explanation.  The output in the file is correct.  What is the reason?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica it’s correct when redirect the output to a file

Comment: It shows that your program is correct, and the console you were using is not. If the output goes faulty after a certain number of lines, perhaps the console's scrolling and buffer settings are incorrect.

Comment: @WeatherVane Ok, I wonder why it is the same even in visual studio.  Is it a system problem?Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your program, it should work fine for values of `N` up to `47`, beyond which you will have undefined behavior when computing the **fib(47)** as the addition will cause a signed integer overflow.

You could use type `unsigned long long` to produce twice as much output (with `printf("%llu\n", fib_number[i])`).

This issue you document is not in the program, but likely comes from your system: either the OS or emulation thereof or the terminal application or emulator built into the IDE.  Try another setup, running the program directly at the shell prompt or redirecting its output to a file.